# SPMenu Field for sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, spgridview

I have written code where it will show the Sharepoint document library in sp grid view.It is showing the grid but i want the default spmenu field for the type icon. please see the attached image. 
Below is the code of mine

```
private void CreateBoundField(string sDataField, string sHeaderText, bool bReadOnly, SPGridView theGridView)
    {
        BoundField field = new BoundField();
        field.DataField = sDataField;
        field.HeaderText = sHeaderText;
        field.HtmlEncode = false;
        field.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080");
        field.HeaderStyle.Font.Names = new string[] { "verdana", "arial", "helvetica", "sans-serif" };
        field.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        if (sHeaderText.ToLower().Equals("type"))
        {
            field.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
            field.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(35);
            field.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(35);
        }
        field.ReadOnly = bReadOnly;
        if (!bReadOnly)
            field.SortExpression = sDataField;
        field.Visible = true;
        theGridView.Columns.Add(field);
    }  

SPGridView gv = new SPGridView();
                gv.ID = "gv";
                gv.EmptyDataText = "No items found!";
                gv.AllowSorting = true;
                gv.AllowFiltering = true;
                gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                gv.EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = true;
                CreateBoundField("Type", "Type", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Title", "Title", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Date", "Date", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("ProcessTask", "ProcessTask", false, gv);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPListItemCollection items = web.Lists["Shared Documents"].Items;            
                dt.Columns.Add("Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                dt.Columns.Add("Date");
                dt.Columns.Add("ProcessTask");
                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    string value = item["ProcessTask"].ToString();
                    value = value.Substring(value.LastIndexOf(";#") + 2);
                    string docicon = SPUtility.ConcatUrls("/_layouts/images",
                    SPUtility.MapToIcon(item.Web, SPUtility.ConcatUrls(item.Web.Url, item.Url), "", IconSize.Size16));
                    dr["Type"] = string.Format("<img src='{0}' />", docicon);
                    dr["Title"] = item.Title;
                    dr["Date"] = item["Created"].ToString().Split(' ')[0];
                    dr["ProcessTask"] = value;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();
                this.Controls.Add(gv);
               SPListItemCollection _GridCollection = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Shared Documents"].Items;
                DataTable _MyDatabale = _GridCollection.GetDataTable();
                gvdetails.DataSource = _MyDatabale;
                gvdetails.DataBind();

}
```

Out put: image is attached [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/02/25/integrating-a-custom-aspnet-application-into-sharepoint-part-2/)'s an example on how to use the `SharePoint:SPMenuField` on a SPGridView.

Basically, you first have to add a `SharePoint:MenuTemplate` control, then a `SharePoint:SPMenuField` to the SPGridView columns collection, with the `MenuTemplateId` pointing to the ID of the `SPMenuField` control previously created.

Comment: Hi Mazzotti, Basically i want default properties for the type value from sharepoint SPMENU field. or view in browser property.. can you help me on that please

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you rephrase? Also, did you check the link I gave you?

Comment: Basically if you see my screen shot which i have posted earlier i want only "View In WebBrowser" and if the Type is visio i wan't to have the option "Edit it in Visio". I am creating the SP Grid Dynamically so i ma not sure how to add SPMENU Field in my code Above. Hope i made it clear

Comment: I can see a CreateBoundField method. What is it?

Comment: It will just create Columns for the table and bind to the Grid.I have used this like below (CreateBoundField("Type", "Type", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Title", "Title", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("Date", "Date", false, gv);
                CreateBoundField("ProcessTask", "ProcessTask", false, gv); Where Type,Title,Date,Process task are my column names for my Grid

Comment: Any luck please i am tiered trying this scenario with my code .let me know if you have achieved this thanks again for your help

Comment: I think you want a ready-made solution to copy-paste effortlessly. This is not the right place. I gave you enough indications for you to achieve what you are after. I told you to add a SPMenuField to the columns collection, and a SPMenuField is derived from a DataControlField. Instantiate it and add it to the gridView with theGridView.Columns.Add(spMenu). I won't add more as you now know all that is needed

Comment: Thanks for your Help Mazzotti. I was able to achieve this with a work around according to my scenario. Asusal you are always awesome helping in this forum

Comment: I'm glad you finally got it to work.